# insert data into database from array

Tags: php, html, arrays

i need to add data to database from array(table). but this POST.php is not working properly. so can you guys please give me any solution for this.

this is the error that it give.

Illegal string offset 'h_name' in C:\wamp\www\confirm\post.php on line 11

line 11 is:  VALUES ('$row[h_name]', '$row[room]', '$row[nors]', '$row[nights]', '$row[euro]', '$row[date]', '09090')";

all inserted value give that error.  Array to string conversion
Thank you.

```
                    </br>
                    <h4 id="italic">Hotel Details :</h4>
                    </br>

                        <div class="reqtable">
                            <table>
                                <tr ><td>Hotel Name</td><td>Room Type</td><td>Number of Rooms</td><td>Nights</td><td>EURO</td><td>Date</td></tr>
                                <tr><td><?php
                                    include "conn.php";
                                    $query = "SELECT h_id, h_name FROM hotels";
                                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conn)); // Run your query

                                    echo '<select name="list[h_name]" id="h_name"  ">';

                                    echo '<option value=""> Choose a Hotel </option>';
                                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                                        echo '<option value="'.$row['h_id'].'">'.$row['h_name'].'</option>';
                                    }

                                    echo '</select>';/

                                        ?>
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                    <?php echo '
                                                <select name="list[room]" id="room"  >
                                                    <option value="">Choose a Room Type</option>
                                                    <option value="1">Single Room</option>
                                                    <option value="2">Double Room</option>         
                                                    <option value="3">Triple Room</option>
                                                    <option value="4">Family Room</option>
                                                    <option value="5">Custom Room</option>
                                                </select>';
                                    ?>
                                </td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="list[nors]" placeholder="Number of Rooms"></td>
                                <td> <input type="text" class="zxc" nname="list[nights]" placeholder="Nights"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="list[euro]" placeholder="euro"></td>
                                <td><input type="date" name="list[date]" placeholder="Date"></td>
                                <td><pre>    </pre></td>
                                <td><input type='button' class='AddNew' value='Add new item'></td></tr>
                                <tr><td>Total</td><td></td><td></td><td><input name="result" id="result"></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
                            </table>    
                        </div>
                            </br>

                            <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Register" color="red" style="width: 77px; height: 50px"></div>

                </form>





post.php(php process)





<?php
    include "conn.php";
    print_r($_POST['list']);





        foreach ($_POST as $row) {
            $query = "INSERT INTO reqhotels (reqh_h_name, reqh_rtype, reqh_nor, reqh_nights, reqh_euro, reqh_date, reqh_req_no) 
                    VALUES ('$row[h_name]', '$row[room]', '$row[nors]', '$row[nights]', '$row[euro]', '$row[date]', '09090')";

            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conn)); 

            if($result > 0) {
                echo"successfull";
            }
            else {
                echo"fail";
            }
        }
?>
```

---

**EDIT :** ported from answer to question : Aug.05

---

this is my html codes. (html table). in here used  a jquery to add some extra rows to this table. so i want to insert all data to database.

table columns:
    rq_h_name, rq_rtype, rq_nors, rq_nights, rq_euro, rq_date

```
 <form action="post.php" method="POST" id="register-form" novalidate="novalidate">

                    </br>
                    <h4 id="italic">Hotel Details :</h4>
                    </br>

                        <div class="reqtable">
                            <table>
                                <tr >
                                    <td>Hotel Name</td>
                                    <td>Room Type</td>
                                    <td>Number of Rooms</td>
                                    <td>Nights</td>
                                    <td>EURO</td>
                                    <td>Date</td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                    <?php
                                        include "conn.php";
                                        $query = "SELECT h_id, h_name FROM hotels";
                                        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conn)); // Run your query

                                        echo '<select name="list[0][]" id="h_name"  ">'; 

                                        echo '<option value=""> Choose a Hotel </option>';
                                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                                            echo '<option value="'.$row['h_id'].'">'.$row['h_name'].'</option>';
                                        }

                                        echo '</select>';

                                    ?>
                                    </td>

                                <td>
                                    <?php echo '
                                                <select name="list[0][]" id="room"  >
                                                    <option value="">Choose a Room Type</option>
                                                    <option value="1">Single Room</option>
                                                    <option value="2">Double Room</option>         
                                                    <option value="3">Triple Room</option>
                                                    <option value="4">Family Room</option>
                                                    <option value="5">Custom Room</option>
                                                </select>';
                                    ?>
                                </td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="list[0][]" placeholder="Number of Rooms"></td>

                                <td> <input type="text" class="zxc" name="list[0][]" placeholder="Nights"></td>

                                <td><input type="text" name="list[0][]" placeholder="euro"></td>

                                <td><input type="date" name="list[0][]" placeholder="Date"></td>

                                <td><input type='button' class='AddNew' value='Add new item'></td></tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>Total</td>
                                    <td><input name="result" id="result"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>    
                        </div>
                            </br>
```

Comment: Seems clear: an array is not a string.  You either have to figure out how to concatenate that array of values into a string OR model a true one-to-many relationship and INSERT each array element into a table with a foreign key relationship to its parent.

Comment: Apart from that there are several other issues here: you add exactly the same value 6 times! That cannot be your intention. Also why are the `$row[0]` in single quotes?

Comment: can you guys please give me any solution to fix this?

Comment: Your form has not even an open tag !! **<form>**. You stuff sequentially values in the list `list[0][]`. How can you expect to get them in the correct order, from the list out ? `foreach ($_POST as $row)` ? give every form element `a unique name` e.g. **<input type="text" name="reqh_nor" placeholder="Number of Rooms">** . Set it `$reqh_nor = $_POST['reqh_nor'];` Get it like `VALUES ('...', '...','".$reqh_nor."',....)`

Comment: there is a form tag in my code. but here its missing

Comment: Do you now with **every element** $_POST has you do an insert into your database. Even for the $_POST['submit'] it runs through the loop !!!

Comment: the problem is this, i have table(html) with value and i want to input this values to database. thats why i used list[0][]. as an array

Comment: **list[0][]** , that's really not necessary make it first in conventional processes. Give every form field a unique name.

Comment: @Lakith : you can not do it that simple : `VALUES ('$row[h_name]',...` . You must qoute `'h_name'` e.g. `"INSERT....VALUES ('".$row['h_name']."','".$row['...'].etc.`

Comment: This is your html part with wrong variables `<select name="list[0][]" id="h_name"` let us please stay with `<select name="list[h_name]" id="h_name`. **I can not help if your code is always different than in my assistance to you**. And the important part how you insert into database **we can not see** !!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably you want to do the following

```
foreach ($_POST['list'] as $row) {
```

or similar instead of current

```
foreach ($_POST as $row) {
```

In your current manner you have an array in array so and the array could not be substituted directly to a string. I'm not sure this will exactly work, but that's the idea you shoud follow and shows the problem you have. Your code is a bit messy so I'won't guarantee you have no other errors.

Comment: what i have posted is not a solution, it shows where you are wrong and why you recieve this error ... no one will give you solution because this code is a mess and it is not placed in a php fiddle ... so you have the idea where is your bottleneck ... try harder to improve your code

Comment: in this context a a loop over a list is completely wrong : `foreach ($_POST['list'] as $row)`  . @Lakith need for an insert all values at once. NOT, with each pass through the loop, a different value. every loop with this single value to build a valid insert, is impossible. Seven values in the array `$_POST['list']` means seven INSERTS !! Each insert with only one valid value.

Comment: the guy changed the intial code ... it was different ... there was `list[0][name]` construction initally

Comment: I know . but to get only a array with all field values , a `foreach loop` is wrong. What about `$row = $_POST['list']` ? No Loop !

Comment: I don't remeber the original code, but the error was produces because $row[0] as it was written in inital code was an array, not a scalar value

Comment: I know , but foreach is wrong in this context. If you want do it that way you can do it ONLY to build the query string . After the query is ready leave the loop and do the insert . I hope you understand what I mean.